# Soap UI. How to validate request before sending it?

Tags: validation, wsdl, request, soapui

I'm testing some web services and i need to validate request (xml message) against wsdl before sending it.
In Pro version of Soap UI using GUI i can do it (alt-v), but i can't do it automatically. i need in some way validate it automatically when i start test project. When our build-server starts run test project.
May be there are some groovy scripts or something else?

Of course, in soap ui there are assertions, but it only working with responses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following Script assertion:

```
def project = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.testSuite.project

def wsdlcontext = project.getInterfaceAt(0).getDefinitionContext()
def validator = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlValidator(wsdlcontext);

def errors = validator.assertRequest(messageExchange, false)

assert errors.length < 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the below script, if you face any problem please let me know.

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory

//Load the XSD from a file
def xsd = new File('/C:/schemaFile.xsd').text

//Get the XML from the response
def xmlHolder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( messageExchange.requestContentAsXml )
def xml = xmlHolder['//result']

def factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
def schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsd)))
def validator = schema.newValidator()

try {
   validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)))
} catch( e ) {
   assert false
}
```